# Help for understanding Danielson-Lanczos lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, proof-writing, signal-processing

The [Danielson-Lanczos lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Danielson-LanczosLemma.html) is the basis for fast Fourier transform algorithms.

Now, I do understand this step

$\displaystyle X_{k} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_{n}\omega^{kn}_{N} =
   \sum_{n=0}^{(N/2)-1} x_{2n}\omega^{k(2n)}_{N} + 
   \sum_{n=0}^{(N/2)-1} x_{2n+1}\omega^{k(2n+1)}_{N}$

but I don't see how the rest follows.

Comment: You may want to provide a reference to the proof of the lemma, so it will be easier to give an answer that uses only techniques you are familiar with.

Comment: The proof for the lemma can be found from the URL in my question. It is supposed to be simple but I do no see where the N/2 comes from the in the exponent. I guess it is written to be as short as possible, omitting some step I just fail to see.

Comment: Oh. Then what exactly is the statement of the lemma? Do you see how to factor out the function $W^n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, keeping that $\omega_N = e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{N}}$, $\hat{x}_n = x_{2n}$, $\tilde{x}_n = x_{2n+1} \; (n = 0, 1, \dots, \frac{N}{2}-1)$, let's regroup terms further:

$$ \begin{align} & X_{k} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_{n}\omega^{kn}_{N} =
   \sum_{n=0}^{(N/2)-1} x_{2n}\omega^{k(2n)}_{N} + 
   \sum_{n=0}^{(N/2)-1} x_{2n+1}\omega^{k(2n+1)}_{N} = \\
   & \sum_{n=0}^{(N/2)-1} \hat{x}_{n}\omega^{2kn}_{N} + 
   \sum_{n=0}^{(N/2)-1} \tilde{x}_{n}\omega^{2kn}_{N}\cdot\omega^k_N =  
   \sum_{n=0}^{(N/2)-1} \hat{x}_{n}\omega^{kn}_{N/2} + 
   \omega^k_N \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{(N/2)-1} \tilde{x}_{n}\omega^{kn}_{N/2} = \\
   & \hat{X}_k + \omega^k_N \cdot \tilde{X}_k ,
\end{align}$$
where $\hat{X}$ and $\tilde{X}$ denote Fourier transforms of $\hat{x}$ and $\tilde{x}$ (they're both $N/2$-length vectors).
My $\hat{x}$ and $\tilde{x}$ stand for $F^e$ and $F^o$ in description from your link.